# PHP : Parser asp page

Tags: php, parsing

Googd morning, can I parser an asp page with php for to take the html tag code ?

How can I take this value `<a href="xxx">**VALUE TO TAKE**</a>` from an asp page ?

Comment: Do you mean you want to parse Classic ASP source code? Or HTML generated by Classic ASP? Or do you mean one of the above but for ASP.NET? And which programming language is the ASP using? VBScript? Something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can use [file_get_contents('http://www.example.com/myasp.asp');](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.file-get-contents.php) to get the file in a string and then use some RegEx to get the data you need.

Somthing like

```
<?php
 /*GET ALL LINKS FROM http://www.w3schools.com/asp/default.asp*/
 $page = file_get_contents('http://www.w3schools.com/asp/default.asp');
preg_match_all("/<a.*>(.*?)<\/a>/", $page, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);
echo "All links : <br/>";
foreach($matches as $match){
    echo $match[1]."<br/>";
}
?>
```

Comment: there are same exemple ? please