# PHP parser ASP page

Tags: php, parsing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP : Parser asp page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7515634/php-parser-asp-page)

I have this tag into asp page

```
<a class='Lp' href="javascript:prodotto('Prodotto.asp?C=3')">AMARETTI VICENZI GR. 200</a>
```

how can i parser this asp page for to have the text **AMARETTI VICENZI GR. 200** ?

This is the code that I use but don't work :

```
<?php
$page = file_get_contents('http://www.prontospesa.it/Home/prodotti.asp?c=12'); 
preg_match_all('#<a href="(.*?)" class="Lp">(.*?)</a>#is', $page, $matches); 

$count = count($matches[1]); 
for($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++){ 
    echo $matches[2][$i];  
} 
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You're regular expression (in `preg_match_all`) is wrong. It should be `#<a class='Lp' href="(.*?)">(.*?)</a>#is` since the class attribute comes first, not last and is wrapped in single quotes, not double quotes.

You should highly consider using [`DOMDocument`](http://ca.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) and [`DOMXPath`](http://ca.php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php) to parse your document instead of regular expressions.

**DOMDocument/DOMXPath Example:**

```
<?php

// ...

$doc = new DOMDocument;
$doc->loadHTML($html); // $html is the content of the website you're trying to parse.

$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
$nodes = $xpath->query('//a[@class="Lp"]');

foreach ( $nodes as $node )
  echo $node->textContent . PHP_EOL;
```

Comment: this code don't work with asp page there are same erros :
Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTML() [domdocument.loadhtml]: Misplaced DOCTYPE declaration in Entity, line: 22 in /home/content/n/9/5/n95161273/html/vampire_diaries/parser.php on line 4

Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTML() [domdocument.loadhtml]: htmlParseStartTag: misplaced <html> tag in Entity, line: 102 in /home/content/n/9/5/n95161273/html/vampire_diaries/parser.php on line 4

Comment: Those are just warnings, DOM still loads the file. Set libxml_use_internal_errors() to true before the load call, false after, so you suppress them.

Answer (score 0):

You have to modify the regular expression a little based on the HTML code of the page you are getting the content from:

```
'#<a class=\'Lp\' href="(.*?)">(.*?)</a>#is'
```

Note that the class is first and it is surrounded by single quotes not double. I tested and it works for me.